# Returning value from a method in Java that does not match the type of the class

Tags: java, return-value

I have just recently started working with Java with some previous experience in Python and am trying to figure out the similarities and differences.

I am currently working with a method that is supposed to return a list with Player-names based on user input. However, I notice some differences in the code structure in Java compared to Python. I have this method:

```
Player[] inputPlayers() {
        // TODO
    
        List<String> playerListStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("How many players do you wish to add? > ");
        int numberOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();

        IntStream.range(1, numberOfPlayers+1).forEachOrdered(n -> {
            System.out.printf("What is Player %ds name? > ", n);;
            String playerName = sc.next();
            playerListStrings.add(playerName);
        });

        return playerListStrings;   // For now
    }
```

So I am basically trying to return the list of names. However, in Visual Studio I am greeted with the warning:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to Ex4ReadPlayers.Player[]Java(16777235)`

I have tried to match the output type to the class which is the "solution" advised by VS but this unfortunately does not solve my problem. Could someone explain the differences between Python- and Java return statements? Do they have the same functionality?

Comment: `Player[]` is an array not a `List`.  A `List` would be something like `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Nexevis Thank you! However, my question was how does this differ from Python? (Is it necessary to return a type matching the class?)

Comment: @Leopold Wahlbeck I recommend you re-read your title then, and tag the question with Python.  Currently you basically have 2 completely unrelated questions in the same question.  If you wanted to make it clear what you are asking, post the version in Python that _does_ work and show us the two versions, then people would understand what you want, or what you are confused by

Comment: As a guess of your confusion, Java requires a declared return type on method definition that matches the type of the `return`, where Python not need a return type as Python is a dynamic language and can thus `return` anything in each function. Currently in Java, your code is basically like you told your code "I want an integer returned from this method", but then you actually just returned a `String` instead.  This is why there is an error.  Python does not ask this question

Comment: Off-topic, since the comments make it clear that this is a question about a difference between Java and Python. But, `return playerListStrings;` could be fixed by something like `return playerListStrings.toArray(new Player[0]);`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-